# Using Redis on Azure with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, azure, doctrine-orm, redis

I am trying to connect Symfony2 with Redis server on Azure but can't figure out where to put the hostname, port and key and other details (if required which I am not aware of).

composer.json

```
"predis/predis": "1.*",
"snc/redis-bundle": "1.1.x-dev"
```

config.yml configured as per [this tutorial](http://olegpuzanov.com/2015/02/01/using-redis-for-doctrine-caching-in-symfony2/)

```
snc_redis:
  # configure predis as client
  clients:
      default:
          type: predis
          alias: default
          dsn: projectrdev.redis.cache.windows.net
      doctrine:
          type: predis
          alias: doctrine
          dsn: projectrdev.redis.cache.windows.net
  # configure doctrine caching
  doctrine:
      metadata_cache:
          client: doctrine
          entity_manager: default
          document_manager: default
      result_cache:
          client: doctrine
          entity_manager: [default]
      query_cache:
          client: doctrine
          entity_manager: default
```

As per Predis [documentation](https://github.com/nrk/predis#connecting-to-redis) clients can be configured but now sure how that works in Symfony environment.

Comment: check out this article http://athlan.pl/symfony2-redis-session-handler/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we should Enable the non-SSL endpoint for PHP integration.
[image]

And you need to combine redis dsn connection string in the following format: `redis://[password@]host[:port][/db]`

E.g, in the `config.yml` file in your symfony2 application, you can config like:

`snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://{password}@{your_redis_name}.redis.cache.windows.net`

And have a test in a controller function:

`use Snc\RedisBundle\Doctrine\Cache\RedisCache;
use Predis\Client;
...
...
$redis = $this->container->get('snc_redis.default');
$val = $redis->incr('foo:bar');
echo $val;`

Comment: What's the password? The primary access key?

Comment: @ChrisHarrison, yep.